# Surjectivity of $f(z)=\frac{(1+z)^2}{(1-z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I am trying to prove that the function $f:A\longrightarrow H^+$, with $f(z)=\frac{(1+z)^2}{(1-z)^2}$, $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1, Imz>0\}$ and $H^+=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Imz>0\}$, is bijective.

I have managed to prove that it is injective but I am struggling to prove that it is surjective. I thought about seeing the function as the composition of the functions $h(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ and $g(z)=z^2$, trying to prove they are both surjective, but it did not work because I do not know what the domain of $g$ would be.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With surjectivity, solve for $f$ explicitly in terms of $z$

Answer (score 1):

To achieve $w=f(z)=1+\frac{4z}{1-z^2}$, rearrange to $z^2+\frac{4z}{w-1}-1=0$. The roots are $\pm z_0^{\pm1}$ with $z_0:=\frac{2}{1-w}+\sqrt{\frac{4}{(1-w)^2}+1}$. They have product $-1$ but aren't $\pm1$ for finite $w$, so exactly one of them has modulus $<1$. So $z_0$ is a unit complex number, and it and $-z_0^{-1}$ are of the form $\pm a+ib$. We need only check $\Im w>0\implies\Im z>0$ by showing the roots' sum has positive imaginary part; indeed, this sum is $\frac{4(1-w^\ast)}{|1-w|^2}$, with imaginary part greater than $\frac{4}{|1-w|^2}$.